# Django admin panel CSS files are denied to access to GC bucket

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, django-admin, bucket

In my Django rest framework project, I have used the filter from django admin panel to filter users
This is what I'm using :
[my codein admin.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mxDv.png) based on their profile. This work fine in my local host [localhost filtering users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fxwl.png)
Now I'm hosting my project on GCP, once I push to live staging the screen display like this :
[the panel after pushing to staging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awdhl.png) .
What I got in the console when I go to filter users is [console when I use the filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W5xG.png)
[the network tab in condole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjVDV.png) [when I click over one of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDHQo.png)

Thanks a lot of any suggestions

https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/454

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.